# American European living in UK. Lost EU passport. Can I travel on American passport within EU?

Tags: visas, usa, uk, customs-and-immigration, schengen-visas

My concern is that re-entering the UK with my american passport will log me into the system as a tourist instead as my current resident status.

Does this mean I need to re-enter the UK when I get my EU passport back within the duration of the implicit US tourist visa?

Does anyone know how this works?

Comment: Do you have a UK Biometric Residence Permit?

Comment: @David I do not think so. What are your initial impression? Happy for any feedback even if you do not have a clear cut answer to the question.

Comment: In your case I would apply for a new passport as fast as possible. That way you will not have any problems crossing the borders. But I am not sure what is the legal status.

Comment: Having a BRP would indicate you have a long-term (visa'd) residency in the UK. Without a BRP, I imagine you're resident in the UK as an EU citizen. I see two issues with UK entry if UKVI sees you as a US citizen tourist: one, you'd not be permitted to work (which you may as an EU citizen exercising freedom of movement, and second, you'd have to depart the UK as required by the time limits of your entry, then re-enter with your EU passport. In any event, I agree with Willeke: get your EU passport replaced.

Comment: @David Thanks for the input. I definitely plan on getting it replaced. My question is whether I can travel with the passport I still have without repercussion. If I understand you correctly, that is not the case? Thanks!

Comment: I'm sorry, @lostmystuff123, I haven't posted an Answer because I don't know specifically if using your US passport will cause UKVI to enter you as a "tourist," or will cause any other "repercussions" to your status. Remember, you've not disclosed what your status is, nor have you said what "repercussions" might affect you. We're guessing here.

Comment: As the UK is currently in the EU, EU citizens have the right to enter and to work. This isn’t contingent on them entering on their EU passport. Any conditions stamped into a US passport wouldn’t apply to them. There would never be any need to reenter to exercise freedom of movement. That aside, do you have an ID card from your EU country? You can use that to enter the UK too.

Comment: @David EU citizens' rights take precedence over the rights conferred by a BRP.  It would be very unusual indeed for an EU citizen to have a BRP.  The precedence also means that an EU citizen is permitted to remain in the UK indefinitely and to work even after being granted leave to enter as a visitor (see schedule 3 of the 2016 regulations).  Furthermore, OP should not be admitted as a visitor because as a resident of the UK he or she is not qualified.

Comment: @phoog Yes, I understand that, and did at the time I asked if the OP had a BRP, which was my clumsy attempt to find out what "resident status" meant. I didn't know if the OP was in the UK as an EU citizen exercising his EU rights, or as an American with a BRP. WIthout knowing the kind of residence, it wasn't at all clear what'd happen if the OP appeared at the UK border seeking entry.

Answer (score 3):

First, as noted by [MJeffryes](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/28009/mjeffryes) in a helpful [comment](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/149245/american-european-living-in-uk-lost-eu-passport-can-i-travel-on-american-passp/149259#comment369942_149245), you can use an EU national ID card instead of an EU passport to enter the UK, if you have one.  This is fundamental in the EU's free movement directive ([2004/38/EC](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX:02004L0038-20110616)) and the UK's implementing [Immigration (EEA) Regulations](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/uksi/2016/1052).

The relevant part of the directive is Article 5(1):

> Article 5
>
> Right of entry
>
> 1.  Without prejudice to the provisions on travel documents applicable to national border controls, Member States shall grant Union citizens leave to enter their territory with a valid *identity card* or passport....

(emphasis added)

The relevant part of the regulations is rule 11(1):

> PART 2
> EEA RIGHTS
>
> Right of admission to the United Kingdom
> 11.—(1) An EEA national must be admitted to the United Kingdom on arrival if the EEA national produces a valid *national identity card* or passport issued by an EEA State.

(emphasis added)

Second, you can enter as an EU citizen without an EU passport by invoking the provision in both the directive and the regulations that allows you to prove "by other means" that you are entitled to do so.

The relevant part of the directive is Article 5(4):

> 4.  Where a Union citizen, or a family member who is not a national of a Member State, does not have the necessary travel documents or, if required, the necessary visas, the Member State concerned shall, before turning them back, give such persons every reasonable opportunity to obtain the necessary documents or have them brought to them within a reasonable period of time *or to corroborate or prove by other means* that they are covered by the right of free movement and residence.

(emphasis added)

The relevant part of the regulations is rule 11(4):

> (4) Before an immigration officer refuses admission to the United Kingdom to a person under this regulation because the person does not produce on arrival a document mentioned in paragraph (1) or (2), the immigration officer must provide every reasonable opportunity for the document to be obtained by, or brought to, the person *or allow the person to prove by other means* that the person is—
>
> (a) an EEA national;
>
> ...

(emphasis added)

Now I do not know what "other means" might be sufficient, so it might be more expedient for you just to enter as a visa-free visitor.  In fact that might be problematic, because one requirement for that is to be a "genuine visitor," which you most certainly are not.  But suppose you are in fact granted leave to enter as such.  That leads to the next point.

Third, even if you enter as a "third-country" national visitor, you still enjoy the rights of an EU citizen because you still *are* an EU citizen.  This is a good thing, because if it were not true, you would be obliged not only to leave the UK within six months, but also to *refrain from working while you were in the UK.*  Most people in your situation will be relieved to find out that they are not required to take a leave of absence from their employment until they can get a new passport or ID card.  This is made explicit in the regulations in the first paragraph of Schedule 3:

> SCHEDULE 3
> EFFECT ON OTHER LEGISLATION
>
> Leave under the 1971 Act
> 1.  Where a person has leave to enter or remain under the 1971 Act which is subject to conditions and that person also has a right to reside under these Regulations, *those conditions do not have effect for as long as the person has that right to reside.*

(emphasis added)

So, to answer your questions explicitly:

> My concern is that re-entering the UK with my american passport will log me into the system as a tourist instead as my current resident status.

That might happen, but no ill will come of it.  It's merely an administrative concern.  If anyone suggests that you've overstayed, you can just tell them that you're an EU citizen.

> Does this mean I need to re-enter the UK when I get my EU passport back within the duration of the implicit US tourist visa?

No.

A final caveat: the UK is currently slated to leave the EU on January 31st, 2020.  The explicit precedence given to EU rights may or may not persist beyond that date.  It would be best to register for the [EU settlement scheme](https://www.gov.uk/settled-status-eu-citizens-families) before then, whether using your EU passport or ID card, to ensure that you do not end up as a test case.